# How to show the errors in the template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

Working on a simple project using Django, and just finished the login/register form. What I'm trying to do is to show up the errors when the user doesn't do something in the right way(ex: not matching the password)
I did the login/register form by using this library `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout` and It did pretty well.

How can I show the errors in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import messages in your views.py

```py
from django.contrib import messages
```

and use it like given below

```py
def signUp(request):
    # Code here
    if (condition):
        messages.error(request, "message")
```

Here, the error is the message tag and the second argument of the `messages.error` function is the actual message. 
Then in your html file run this for loop where you wanted to show the error

```
  {% for message in messages %}
  <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Message: </strong> {{message}}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

There are 5 message tags -

- debug
- info
- warning
- success
- error